# GCP data centre location has any effect on response time

Tags: server, google-cloud-platform

1.How much affect a data center location has on server response time?
2.How secure is the network between servers and client say in terms of sniffing,any specific security measure taken?

Answer (score 1):

1. The location of the data center will affect the latency between it and the client. Ideally, you want to choose a data center in a region/zone closest to the majority of the clients it will be serving. That said, [request from anywhere in the world will hit the nearest edge network device and will then travel over the Google's backbone](https://peering.google.com/#/infrastructure). This provides low global latency, but there is still lower latency if the data center is closer
2. All traffic between GCP resources is secure since it does not leave the Google network. Traffic between an external client and a GCP resource is not secured by default since the traffic has to travel through the internet. There are multiple ways to secure this traffic such as Cloud VPN or using SSL certificates for applications or Load Balancers.

Keep in mind that IaaS resources give you almost full control and so it is up to the user to secure what is deployed